# Microsoft-Cognitive Bing Search API ID

Tags: bing-api, azure-marketplace, bing-search

How can I lookup the Bing Search API ID on my account? The format is supposed to be as follows AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA= but I am unable to find it in my Azure Marketplace dashboard after signing up for the Cognitive Services Account. I'm currently only seeing the Subscription ID and it's not in the format listed above.

Comment: I get this ? responseData = "{\"error\":{\"code\":\"401\",\"message\":\"Access denied due to invalid subscription key or wrong API endpoint. Make sure to provide a valid key for an active subscription and use a correct regional API endpoint for your resource.\"}}"

Answer (score -1):

Portal -> Cognitive Services Accounts -> (Click on your service) -> Keys -> Key 1 and Key 2